# Prove that $(\Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z_2, +)$ is not isomorphic to $(\Bbb Z_4 \times \Bbb Z_2, +)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

> Prove that $(\Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z_2, +)$ is not
>   isomorphic to $(\Bbb Z_4 \times \Bbb Z_2, +).$

I believe that both groups have the same cardinality, however, it is not injective as the identity element in both groups are $(0,0,0)$ and $(0,0)$ respectively and so $1$ from $\Bbb Z_2$ would have to map to $1, 2$ and $3$ from $\Bbb Z_4$. Is my thought process correct?

Comment: note:  only one has elements of order $4$

Comment: \times gives the multiplication symbol

Comment: "*so 1 from $\Bbb Z_2$ would have to map to 1,2 and 3 from $\Bbb Z_4$*"  I don't know what you are trying to say here... but it doesn't sound correct.  Make sure you stop and fully understand the definitions involved.

Comment: I know next to nothing about group theory but it seems you want to show that there is no group isomorphism from $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$. Well they both have four elements which might make one think they're the same. But if you think of this as the binary representations of the numbers $0-3$ they add $\pmod4$ in $\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$ so $01_2+01_2=10_2$but in $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ when adding $0,1$ to itself you would not carry the $1$ to get $1,0$, you would get $0,0$ so they're not isomorphic.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing $1$ (the identity) and $\mathbf{0}$ here. It is a problem with using $1_G$ as the identity too often over $e_G$ (there are arguments for both). The identity in the first group is $(0,0,0)$ and in the second $(0,0)$. Certainly an isomorphism would have to send $(0,0,0)$ to $(0,0)$ or vise versa. But this hasn't told you anything about an isomorphism between them because *every* homomorphism between them has this problem.

Perhaps what you are thinking is trying to map a generator '1' in one to another. But neither of these groups are cyclic. The element $(1,1,1)$ does not generate the first group and $(1,1)$ does not generate the second. It is almost always the case that $(1,1,\ldots,1)$ does not generate $C_{n_1} \times \cdots \times C_{n_k}$, where $C_{n_i}$ is the cyclic group of order $n_i$. [There are some special cases when it does. You learn about these in the Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian Groups.] But here's a hint:

**HINT.** An isomorphism preserves the order of elements, i.e. if $\phi$ is an isomorphism of groups, then $g$ and $\phi(g)$ have the same order. So isomorphic finite groups have the same number of elements of a given order. Can you find an element of $\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ of 'higher' order that cannot be found in $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$?

Alternatively, notice that if $g \in \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$, then $g+g= (0,0,0)$ for all $g$. But what about the element $\phi(g+g)$ as $g$ varies over all $g \in \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$? Can you use the properties of an homomorphism $\phi$ to show that if $\phi$ were an isomorphism that this cannot hold for *all* possible $\phi(g)$? That is, can you find $h \in \mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ so that $h+h \neq (0,0)$? If so, can there be a $g \in \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ with $\phi(g)=h$?

Comment: So, having identified (0,0,0) and (0,0) as identities of both groups, can I do a proof by contradiction? Assuming they are isomorphic, any element of $\Bbb Z_2$ x $\Bbb Z_2$ x $\Bbb Z_2$ should equal to the group's identity when under the group operation unto itself, and the same should apply for $\Bbb Z_4$ x $\Bbb Z_2$. Then finding an element in $\Bbb Z_4$ x $\Bbb Z_2$ that does not follow this would mean there is a contradiction?

Comment: @J.Cricks That doesn't make any sense. You know that $\phi((0,0,0))=(0,0)$ for any group homomorphism $\phi$. But this tells you nothing else about the map $\phi$. You are trying use $h+\phi((0,0,0))=h$ for all $h \in \mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$. But again, you know this is true because $\phi((0,0,0))$ is the identity $(0,0)$. You won't arrive at any contradiction this way.

Answer (score 0):

One technique which can sometimes be useful is to pick a positive integer $k$ then, for each element, calculate its $k$th power. Then find how many elements arose how many times among the $k$th powers.

Here, $k=2$ is suitable: find the square of each element. In $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$, the identity turns up all 8 times, and this is enough to distinguish this group from any other 8-element group. But the technique can also be useful to distinguish between groups both of which have several elements of order 4 with various elements for their squares.